# Faster output via standard out in Java?

Tags: java, performance, io

In an online judge programming contest problem I am required to output up to 50,000 lines in under 1 second via standard out (in addition to reading in up to 200,000 pairs of integers which I used a buffer for). My logic seems to be correct but I keep getting my submissions turned down for exceeding the 1 second runtime. I stripped down my code logic to just output a constant string and it still exceeds the time limit.

**Is there a faster way to output than using `System.out.println(String s)`for every line of output?**

Comment: If this is a contest, shouldn't you not be soliciting help online?

Comment: Haha, it's OK. The contest has been long since over. This is a online judge problem, I get nothing but brownie points for solving it. I just mentioned it to give the problem some context to explain why I would need to do such a thing.

Comment: What happens if you try to create a large multi-line String via a StringBuider and then print that? Have you tested the times for this yourself?

Comment: @Hovercraft that works, I thought I tried that earlier, but I must have done something wrong. Want to go ahead and answer it so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use a single `System.out.print` call (or the least that makes sense which is to be found out via benchmarking) like this:

```
String str = "line1\nline2\nline3\n ...";
System.out.print(str);
```

**Edit:**

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
        sb.append(i).append("\n");
    }
    String str = sb.toString();
    long nt = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.print(str);
    nt = System.nanoTime() - nt;
    System.out.print("\nTime(ms): " + (double)nt / 1000000);
```

`sb.toString()` is not a free operation.

The above takes ~650ms on my notebook (500,000 instead of the requested 50,000).

**Edit2**: with two other tricks, in case the filling time matters:

- construct the StringBuilder with a sufficient capacity
- don't append
  for every line (the code below appends 200 lines every time, for this
  it uses a temp `sb1`); only possible if every line can have the same
  content. Enjoy.

  ```
  long nt = System.nanoTime();
  StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder(400);
  for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      sb1.append("l").append("\n");
  }
  String strSb1 = sb1.toString();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000000);
  for (int i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
      sb.append(strSb1);
  }

  System.out.print(sb.toString());
  nt = System.nanoTime() - nt;
  System.out.print("\nTime(ms): " + (double)nt / 1000000);
  ```

~500ms in my case.

Comment: The solution would also need a StringBuilder as per my comment to the OP above.

Comment: Would need, just make sure you assign `String str = stringBuilder.toString()` before the `System.out.print` so that the cost of `toString()` is not counted to the time required to output the stuff.

Comment: toString is called no matter what.

Comment: The general idea is that the cost of appending a string line by line and writing that string to standard out once is less than the cost of calling System.out.print() for every line.

Answer (score 5):

As noted above, the solution is to build your`String`with the`StringBuilder` class and then get the result with the`StringBuilder.toString()`method.
This can and should be testable by you.

Answer (score 4):

It is highly likely you are not using enough buffering. If you writing to System.out it will auto-flush every line so grouping a few lines together before you write can add some buffering.  A better approach is to use a proper buffer.

Using a StringBuffer has an inherent cost of growing the buffer.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(long i=0;i<50*1000;i++)
  sb.append("Hello World!\n");
System.out.print(sb);
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.err.printf("Took %d ms%n", time/1000000);
```

prints

```
Took 30 ms.
```

However on Linux, if you know stdout is a file you can write to it directly.

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
String processId = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0];
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/proc/" + processId + "/fd/1");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
final byte[] str = "Hello World!\n".getBytes();
for (long i = 0; i < 50 * 1000; i++) {
  bos.write(str);
}
bos.close();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.err.printf("Took %d ms%n", time/1000000);
```

prints

```
Took 9 ms.
```

However, you do have to be careful how much you optimise the code as you can break the implied rules of the benchmark and not have it accepted. ;)

Comment: There is some merit to using `stdout` directly, but why use Java in this case? Just go for `C` instead of doing it in platform dependent Java.

Comment: You don't have to go as extreme as the second example. You can just buffer System.out and write bytes to it. The timing is so quick, even on a cheap laptop, it hardly matters.

Comment: Buffering the output seems to be the best option, it's also what I recommended see my answer.

Comment: I thought you were suggesting using `StringBuilder` which is like buffering though a more obvious choice might be `BufferedOutputStream`

Comment: On my machine buffering `System.out` via `BufferedOutputStream` takes `~60ms` with the standard buffer of 8K and `~24ms` with a buffer of 100000 bytes (each line looks like `"l\n"`, 50k lines). So yes, buffering the out stream can be really fast, faster than my way(`~50ms`) with a proper buffer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the underlying OS. If I were you I'd just write to a file, which is much faster.

If you can't do that, and you are running your app. on an OS with blocking console out put (as opposed to non blocking console out put), you could benefit from writing your own asynchronous logger. Log4j has logger implementations that do this for example.

Basically you'll have an executor service to which you submit the strings, and let it write to the console. While that thread is writing, your original working thread will continue to work, thereby reducing the loss due to waiting for the message to flush.

The console output in turn is also utilized better, because by the time it has finished flushing, new messages are already ready.

This way you might be able to increase your throughput.